# Has anyone tried the Piwik PRO api in R?

Tags: r, api, httr, rcurl, matomo

I would like to use the Piwik PRO api in R, but cannot find an example for the code.

Does anyone know how to format this into R code? (Or can help me point to a source which will help me to do this myself?)

```
    curl -X POST 'https://<domain>/auth/token' -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{
"grant_type": "client_credentials",
"client_id": "your_generated_client_id",
"client_secret": "your_generated_client_secret"
 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the [httr package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/httr/index.html).
Authentication code should look something like this:

```
library(httr) 

url <- "" 

payload <- "{ \"grant_type\": \"client_credentials\", \"client_id\": \"\", \"client_secret\": \"\" }" 

encode <- "json" 

response <- VERB("POST", url, body = payload, add_headers(Content_Type = 'application/json'), content_type("application/json"), encode = encode) 

content(response, "text")
```